# How to bind my app to CMD+Tab?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, uiaccessibility

I wish to develop an alternative app-switcher like for example [Witcher](http://manytricks.com/witch/) and [Hyperswitch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch), to be accessed by Cmd+Tab.

Now I notice that they both need Accessibility Options and use some form of staying in memory.

The question is, what are the steps to take here? Do I use some background process to listen to cmd+tab and then just show a window? Can I let my app just register the cmd+tab shortcut inside the OS?

Also, am I correct in thinking the Accessibility Options are needed to bring the selected app to the foreground? Or is it for something else?

Comment: Start with this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3. And yes, the user must approve your app using the Accessibility Options to enable it.